# Recursively scan table based on linked id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DynamoDB like one bellow. The id is the primary key and linked_id is a secondary index

```
id|value|linked_id
1 | one | #NULL
8 | two | #NULL
2 | two | 1
6 | two | 8
3 | two | 2
```

Is it possible to make a query/scan in DynamoDB to fetch all parent items recursively?
For example, when I pass id 3, it returns the row 3, then row 2 because of linked_id is not #NULL and we have a row with id 2, which is equal to linked_id from the row 3.

If linked_id is #NULL - stop querying. I've used SQL query with a subquery, but it takes forever

UPD 1. The result has to be following

```
id|value|linked_id
1 | one | #NULL
2 | two | 1
3 | two | 2
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use `.pipe` to chain the queries. Although I am having difficulty understanding the question. When we query with linked_id : 2, why should it return row 1 or row 2?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that the table name is ABC, and we have a dbModel to Query/scan the table.

```
function main(id){
    return ABC.getItems(id)
        .pipe(getChild.bind(null)
        .execute();
}

  function getChild(queryResult, next){
    if(!queryResult.items.length) return;
    return Promise.map(queryResult.items, item =>{
      return ABC.getItems(item.linked_id).execute().then((res)=>allValues.push(res.items));
    })
      .then(()=> next());
}
```